# Select column from matrix where some other column satisfies given condition

Tags: matlab, matrix

My matrix has 10 columns. I want to select all rows where the first column is less than 4. If I use

```
data(data(:,1)<4)
```

Only the first column is selected.
How do I display all corresponding column values?
How do I select a single corresponding column, e.g., select column 2 where value of column1<4?

Comment: @jandegier why did you delete your answer?

Comment: I am using my phone without MATLAB, and got confused about the rows and columns in the question. And I expected that someone else would answer it correctly within seconds..

Comment: @JandeGier pity, you got it right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data(data(:,1)<4,:)
```

: indicates all columns. Since data is 2-d matrix, you need to input two parameters, one for row and one for column.

If you need specific columns like column 2

```
data(data(:,1)<4,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
data( data(:,1) < 4, : )
```

Comment: Further to this, to select a single corresponding column, eg: column 2, you would use the following: `data( data(:,1) < 4, 2)`